# How do I properly test my javascript code from an external file?

Tags: javascript, html

I keep getting this error: {"code":"MethodNotAllowedError","message":"POST is not allowed"} when submitting my HTML form. My Javascript seems to work fine because it works when I put it inside the HTML in a script tag, but when I try to use it in its own file, I get this error on a form submit. I am launching this code from Adobe Dreamweaver and am using the realtime preview mode in Chrome/Safari. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Calculator</title>
<link href="dopeStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post" id="numberForm">
<label for="enterNumber">Enter any number to multiply it by 10:  </label>
<input type="number" id="enterNumber"><br>
<input type="submit"><br>
<label for="result">Result: </label>
<input type="number" id="result">
</form>

</body>
<script src="trippyJavascript.js"></script>
</html>
```

& here is the Javascript:

```
function calculate()
{
    'use strict';
     var numInput = document.getElementById('enterNumber').value;
     numInput*= 10;
     document.getElementById('result').value = numInput;
     return false;
}

function init()
{
'use strict';
document.getElementByID('numberForm').onsubmit = calculate;
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: At `document.getElementByID` should be lowercase `d` at `ID`. `input` elements do not have a `name` attribute. Default action of `form` submission is not prevented.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have tested you code.The mistake is 'document.getElementById' in this way not 'document.getElementByID'.

```
function calculate()
{
    'use strict';
     var numInput = document.getElementById('enterNumber').value;
     numInput*= 10;
     document.getElementById('result').value = numInput;
     return false;
}

function init()
{
'use strict';
document.getElementById('numberForm').onsubmit = calculate;
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: This worked. What a small mistake! I have to learn to be more careful. Thank you so much.